# HOW TO HIDE/IGNORE ?RVN in Icefaces

Tags: icefaces

Hello fellow developer,im getting problem when i have to hide the, for example, /Login.html?rvn=1, i want to hide rvn parameter in icefaces,s that possible?iam using icefaces 1.8.2..

i have searching that method and o found thats a way to hide rvn,by adding in web.xml,

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.ignoreRvn</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

but,the rvn is still shows up,could everyone help me?

thanks for your comment n sorry for my bad english :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thinks the best way to do this is by using prettyfaces,so we can hide the the url in icefaces,and using custom url,,we can hack it too :D